# Hide Sticky Header Bar

Tags: html, css, header

I have a sticky header pinned to the top of the page. I want it to stick to the top normally but hide when scroll down, just like the top bar in StackOverflow. I could not find the solution on other similar SO threads. I need a css/html only solution if possible.
Here is my code for that div.

```
 #topbar
 { 
  background-color: #E6E6E6 ;
  width: 100% ;
  padding-left: 850px ;
  padding-top: 3px ;
  color: brown ;
  top: 0px ;
  left: 0px ;
  position: fixed ;
  height: 33px ;
}
```

Comment: I dont know why the user deleted it, but the answer works perfectly like a charm. Thanks.!

Comment: I thought it didn't fix your problem.  XD

Comment: Which one ? the css or jquery ?

Comment: Awesome ! I just noticed that you used `position:fixed;` after I answered the jquery one. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
position:fixed;
```

to

```
position:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code here, it works fine:

```
window.onscroll=function(){

    $(window).scrollTop()>0?$("#topbar").fadeOut():$("#topbar").fadeIn();

}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpwaw/